# SwiftUI: How to remove extra space in lists, when .deleteDisabled(true)?

Tags: ios, list, swiftui

When the ability to delete is disabled [.deleteDisabled(true)] on a list and the list's edit button [EditButton()] is pressed, the extra space to the left of each list item still appears as if it were still show the delete buttons (I don't want to do multi-selection of list rows either, just organize the list items individually), but I haven't found or been able to remove that space on the left, which belongs to the delete buttons and I want strip to make the text fill the entire line, because the stripping capability still leaves that space even if it's disabled.

```
List {
    ForEach(projectListVM.projects
            .filter{filterFavorites ?
            $0.isFavorite == true :
            ($0.isFavorite || !$0.isFavorite)},
            id: \.id) { itemProject in
        ProjectListRowScreen(itemProject: itemProject, projectListVM: projectListVM)
    }
    .onMove(perform: moveItem)
    .deleteDisabled(true)
    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
}
```

**ProjectListRowScreen.swift**

Answering to George: Can you post the code from ProjectListRowScreen?

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    NavigationLink {
        ProjectDetailScreen(projectVM: itemProject)
    } label: {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                if itemProject.isFavorite {
                    Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                        .frame(width: 18, alignment: .top)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(itemProject.color.isEmpty ? tagColors[0] : itemProject.color))//Color("Favorite"))
                        .padding(.top, paddingMicro)
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: "cube.fill")
                        .frame(height: 18, alignment: .top)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(itemProject.color.isEmpty ? tagColors[0] : itemProject.color))
                        .padding(.top, paddingMicro)
                }
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(itemProject.title).fontWeight(.thin)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showEditView,
       onDismiss: {projectListVM.fetchAllProjects()},
       content: {ProjectEditScreen(projectItem: itemProject)})
.swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
    Button {
        self.toogleFavorite(projectId: itemProject.id)
    } label: {
        if itemProject.isFavorite {
            Label("Unfavorite", systemImage: "star.slash")
        } else {
            Label("Favorite", systemImage: "star.fill")
        }
    }
    .tint(itemProject.isFavorite ? .gray: .yellow)
}
.swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
    Button(role: .destructive) {
        showConfirmationDelete = true
    } label: {
        Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
    }
    .tint(.red)
    Button {
        showEditView = true
    } label: {
        Label("Edit",systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
    }
    .tint(.blue)
}
.confirmationDialog(
    "Are you sure? Action cannot be undone",
    isPresented: $showConfirmationDelete,
    titleVisibility: .visible,
    actions: {
        Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
            withAnimation {
                self.deleteProjectById(projectId: itemProject.id)
                showConfirmationDelete = false
            }
        }
        Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { showConfirmationDelete = false }
    })
.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 15, leading: 10, bottom: 15, trailing: 10))
.background(Color("BackgroundPanel"))
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerMedium, style: .continuous))
```

[image: The list still shows the space for the delete buttons.]

Comment: I'm afraid you can't.

Comment: Can you post the code from ProjectListRowScreen?

Comment: @George First of all, thank you. Your request is answered in the same question.

Comment: Embed everything into a HStack {  yourView Spacer()  }

Comment: @George Thanks for interest and help, however it hasn't worked for me. The problem continues to occur.

Comment: @miosser You may end up having to create your own list using a LazyVStack. I gave up on that as well.